# How to unlock all the chests in the treasure trove?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Heard the following problem in Google Code Jam. The competition has ended now, so it's okay to talk about it https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2270488/dashboard#s=p3

> Following an old map, you have stumbled upon the Dread Pirate Larry's secret treasure trove!
>
> The treasure trove consists of N locked chests, each of which can only be opened by a key of a specific type. Furthermore, once a key is used to open a chest, it can never be used again. Inside every chest, you will of course find lots of treasure, and you might also find one or more keys that you can use to open other chests. A chest may contain multiple keys of the same type, and you may hold any number of keys.
>
> You already have at least one key and your map says what other keys can be found inside the various chests. With all this information, can you figure out how to unlock all the chests?
>
> If there are multiple ways of opening all the chests, choose the "lexicographically smallest" way.

For the competition there were two datasets, a small dataset with troves of at most 20 chests, and a large dataset with troves as big as 200 chests.

[My backtracking branch-and-bound algorithm](https://github.com/matt-hickford/codejam/blob/master/2013/qualification/treasure/treasure.py) was only fast enough to solve the small dataset. What's a faster algorithm?

Comment: If you are satisfied with an `O(2^n)` algorithm, you can use inclusion-exclusion

Comment: Here is a solution which solves the "large" input in about 10 seconds: https://github.com/tobin/codejam/blob/master/2013/treasure.py

Comment: Now it's down to 1.5 seconds for the large input (-:

Comment: C++ version (with the exact same algorithm as the Python version) solves the large input in 0.25 seconds when compiled with optimizations. (-:  https://github.com/tobin/codejam/blob/master/2013/treasure.cc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surprisingly this problem is solvable via a greedy algorithm.  I, too, implemented it as a memoized depth-first search.  Only afterwards did I notice that the search never backtracked, and there were no hits to the memoization cache.  Only two checks on the state of the problem and the partial solution are necessary to know whether a particular solution branch should be pursued further.  They are easily illustrated with a pair of examples.

First, consider this test case:

```
Chest Number  |  Key Type To Open Chest  |  Key Types Inside
--------------+--------------------------+------------------
1             |  2                       |  1
2             |  1                       |  1 1
3             |  1                       |  1
4             |  2                       |  1
5             |  2                       |  2

Initial keys: 1 1 2
```

Here there are a total of only two keys of type 2 in existence: one in chest #5, and one in your possession initially.  However, *three* chests require a key of type 2 to be opened.  We need more keys of this type than exist, so clearly it is impossible to open all of the chests.  We know immediately that the problem is impossible.  I call this key counting the "global constraint."  We only need to check it once.  I see this check is already in your program.

With just this check and a memoized depth-first search (like yours!), my program was able to solve the small problem, albeit slowly: it took about a minute.  Knowing that the program wouldn't be able to solve the large input in sufficient time, I took a look at the test cases from the small set.  Some test cases were solved very quickly while others took a long time.  Here's one of the test cases where the program took a long time to find a solution:

```
Chest Number  |  Key Type To Open Chest  |  Key Types Inside
--------------+--------------------------+------------------
1             | 1                        | 1
2             | 6                        |
3             | 3                        |
4             | 1                        |
5             | 7                        | 7 
6             | 5                        | 
7             | 2                        |
8             | 10                       | 10
9             | 8                        | 
10            | 3                        | 3
11            | 9                        | 
12            | 7                        |
13            | 4                        | 4
14            | 6                        | 6
15            | 9                        | 9
16            | 5                        | 5
17            | 10                       |
18            | 2                        | 2
19            | 4                        |
20            | 8                        | 8

Initial keys: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

After a brief inspection, the structure of this test case is obvious.  We have 20 chests and 10 keys.  Each of the ten key types will open exactly two chests.  Of the two chests that are openable with a given key type, one contains another key of the same type, and the other contains no keys at all.  The solution is obvious:  for each key type, we have to first open the chest that will give us another key in order to be able to open the second chest that also requires a key of that type.

The solution is obvious to a human, but the program was taking a long time to solve it, since it didn't yet have any way to detect whether there were any key types that could no longer be acquired.  The "global constraint" concerned the quantities of each type of key, but not the order in which they were to be obtained.  This second constraint concerns instead the order in which keys can be obtained but not their quantity.  The question is simply: for each key type I will need, is there some way I can still get it?

Here's the code I wrote to check this second constraint:

```
# Verify that all needed key types may still be reachable
def still_possible(chests, keys, key_req, keys_inside):
    keys = set(keys)         # set of keys currently in my possession
    chests = chests.copy()   # set of not-yet-opened chests

    # key_req is a dictionary mapping chests to the required key type
    # keys_inside is a dict of Counters giving the keys inside each chest

    def openable(chest):
        return key_req[chest] in keys

    # As long as there are chests that can be opened, keep opening
    # those chests and take the keys.  Here the key is not consumed
    # when a chest is opened.
    openable_chests = filter(openable, chests)
    while openable_chests:
        for chest in openable_chests:
            keys |= set(keys_inside[chest])
            chests.remove(chest)
        openable_chests = filter(openable, chests)

    # If any chests remain unopened, then they are unreachable no 
    # matter what order chests are opened, and thus we've gotten into
    # a situation where no solution exists.
    return not chests   # true iff chests is empty
```

If this check fails, we can immediately abort a branch of the search.   After implementing this check, my program ran very fast, requiring something like 10 seconds instead of 1 minute.  Moreover, I noticed that the number of cache hits dropped to zero, and, furthermore, the search never backtracked.  I removed the memoization and converted the program from a recursive to an iterative form.  The [Python solution](https://github.com/tobin/codejam/blob/master/2013/treasure.py) was then able to solve the "large" test input in about 1.5 seconds.  A nearly identical [C++ solution](https://github.com/tobin/codejam/blob/master/2013/treasure.cc) compiled with optimizations solves the large input in 0.25 seconds.

A proof of the correctness of this iterative, greedy algorithm is given in the [official Google analysis](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2270488/dashboard#s=a&a=3) of the problem.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not used to algorithm competitions. I was a bit disturbed about this question: to cut branches in the branch & bound general algorithm, you need to have an idea of the general input you'll have.

Basically, i looked at some of the inputs that were provided in the small set. What happen in this set is that you end up in paths where you can't get any key of some type t: all the remaining keys of this type t are all in chests which have a lock of the same type t. So you are not able to access them anymore.

So you could build the following cut criterion: if there is some chest of type t to be opened, if all remaining keys of types t are in those chests and if you don't have anymore key of this type, then you won't find a solution in this branch.

You can generalize the cut criterion. Consider a graph, where vertices are key types and there is an edge between t1 and t2 if there are still some closed chest in t1 which have a key of type t2. If you have some key of type t1, then you can open one of the chests of this type and then get at least a key to one of the chests accessible from the outgoing edges. If you follow a path, then you know you can open at least one chest of each lock type in this path. But if there is no path to a vertex, you know there is no way you will open a chest represented by this vertex.

There is the cuting algorithm. Compute all reachable vertices from the set of vertices you have a key in your posession. If there are unreachable vertices for which there are still closed chest, then you cut the branch. (This means you backtrack)

This was enough to solve the large set. But i had to add the first condition you wrote:

```
if any(required > keys_across_universe):
    return False
```

Otherwise, it wouldn't work. This means that my solution is weak when the number of keys is very close to the number of chests.

This cut condition is not cheap. It can actually cost O(N²). But it cut so much branches that it is definetely worth it... provided the data sets are nice. (fair ?)

Comment: I looked at the solution proposed by the first contestant. The solution is really near what i'm saying here except that... the cut criterion is not only necessary, it also seems sufficient: if the graph of chest types is connected, then you'll find a solution for sure, provided there is the good number of keys. This means you'll never have to backtrack. The solution is thus not exponential, its polynomial. I'll try to find a proof and explain it.

Comment: Because i thought that to solve this questions, we needed to know more about the input we would get. Actually, this seems to be solvable by a greedy polynomial algorithm, so there is no need of that.

Comment: Another optimization, the empty treasure chests can be inserted after the search into the correct order in linear time, since they don't contribute to the critical path

Comment: Can you construct a test case that isn't "nice" and takes a long time to solve via this greedy algorithm?

Comment: Probably not. I didn't prove it, but it's very likely that the greedy algorithm is correct. It seems that you never need to backtrack, you only have to check the connexity of the graph one step ahead. Either you check at the begining that you have enough keys and you WILL find a solution. Either you don't check it, and if at some point whatever chest you open you fail, this means that there is no solution. In any case, the complexity is polynomial. If this fact is true, then there is no "bad case".

Comment: Your solution and mine are the same.

Answer (score -1):

I was not able to solve this problem too. My algorithm at first was too slow, then I added some enhancements but I guess I failed on something else:

1. As Valentin said, I counted the available keys to quickly discard tricky cases
2. Tried to ignore chests without keys inside on first hit, skipping to the next one
3. Skip solutions starting with higher chests
4. Check for "key-loops", if the available keys were not enough to open a chest (chest contained the key for itself inside)

Performance was good (<2 secs for the 25 small cases), I manually checked the cases and it worked properly but got incorrect answer anyway :P

Comment: They put a very annoying restriction: the solution may be lexicographically the first. This prevent any heuristic in the choice of order like your 2) It also disqualify any best-first search algorithm like A*.

Comment: What if you ignored the key loops for as long as possible, because they are lexiographically flexible? If the key loop isn't needed yet, try something else, and if it works, thats good, but if it benefits us lexiographically we can easily move the key-loop forward. At the end, you can take your order and possibly try to find exactly where your keys are available and excess in order to distribute the empty chests lexiographically as well. (We know they can go at the end, but if we can find someplace earlier, and it helps the lexiographic ordering, then put it there instead)

Comment: Here is my attempt http://pastebin.com/TqWWBKzy it includes some last time attempts to fix it hahah. I tried to not ignore any key loop finding the first solution first. After that, the restrictions applied.

Comment: The restriction isn't annoying: it is a very strong clue indicating the nature of the solution (branch and bound with lexical enumeration).